# weblogic 12c Please enable the DomainRuntimeMBean Server and the Edit MBean Server in this domain's configuration

Tags: weblogic12c

On my windows 7 64bit machine, I completely install weblogic 12c but when I log into the admin console it gave me this error:

Please enable the DomainRuntimeMBean Server and the Edit MBean Server in this domain's configuration

I have tried uninstall and do a fresh install but to no avail. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the pending folder within your domain root and restart the server. The default domain may be corrupted.

http://weblogicfordummies.blogspot.com/2008/10/wls10please-enable-domainruntimembean.html

Comment: There is no pending folder in the domain root of weblogic 12c. I saw this link early but it didn't help. Thanks anyway. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Sure a few other ideas:

Try connecting via the IP address and not the machine name (e.g. http://127.0.0.1/console)

Can you run offline WLST to try and set those two values to true?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried it and it works perfectly well. But what was really the problem?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure. I have only seen this happen one time before. The only thing(s) I can think of is that the hostname is somehow mapped to multiple hosts or something. Try checking listen-address in your config.xml to be sure it looks right.

Comment: I resolved issue when replaced an '_' in hostname of server with Weblogic with '-'.